# GATT Error 133 when connecting to raspberry pi 3b+ but not when connecting to arduino?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

To sumerize what I want to accomplish here:
I want to simulate sensors on a raspberry pi and make them available through bluetooth low energy to an android phone.

So what works:
Connecting with "nRF Connect" app to arduino.
Connecting with own app to arduino.

What sometimes works seemingly at random:
Connecting with "nRF Connect" to rbpi.

What doesn't work:
Connecting with own app to rbpi.

When errors occur with the nRF Connect app it tells me a GATT error 133 error occured, that is the same error that I receive in my app, but my app is never able to connect. The just serves as verification tool so as to determain that the problem is not with my app.
But there must be something diffrent because it does work most/some of the time with the nRF Connect app.
On the other hand if something is wrong with it, it should't work with the arduino but it does work.

What do you guys think?
What is the cause of the problem?
The app or the rbpi?
Ive seen online that error 133 has been a very sticky problem and have not seen concrete solutions for it.

Comment: Are you seeing this error on the app's side or the RPi's side? Error 133 normally means "Something's gone wrong, but not sure what." I've experienced this error when connecting an Android app to some Bluetooth modules, but not other modules. I'm inclined to think it's related to the way Android handles BLE. Have you tried using an iOS device to compare?

Comment: Yes I am getting this error code on the app side. No I have not tried that yet. But it's weird, if there was something wrong with the way android connects using ble than I should expect that the nrf connect app from Nordic Semiconductor wouldnt be able to connect either.

Comment: Not necessarily. Sometimes it's the way the Android app is written to handle BLE comms. I've had to completely rewrite the BLE interface on Android apps to reliably talk with BLE modules. Error 133 is used for any error that has not been covered by the previous 132 error codes. Have you tried on a different Android phone?

Comment: I found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The raspberry pi 3b+ has a dual mode bluetooth chip.
In de code on the android side of things you use the method connectGatt() to connect to the remote ble gatt server. You would expect that it would naturally connect to the LE side of the bluetooth chip of the rbpi but apperiantly this is not the case.
This post provided me with the answer:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90696/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-services-not-found-on-android